# How badly can the Lebesgue differentiation theorem fail?

Tags: integration, geometric-measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ is integrable. Is it true that
$$
\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{\displaystyle\int_{B_r(0)}f(y)~\mathrm dy}{r^{n-1}}=0 \quad ?
$$
This is obvious if $0$ is a Lebesgue point of $f$ or if $n=1$, but I would like to know if it's true in general.

Comment: $|x|^{-\alpha}$ with $1 \leq \alpha <n$ is an example when $n>1$.

Comment: Thanks, it was easier than I thought. You should post your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Metafune has given an example of the limit failing to be $0$ at a particular point - namely for $n > 1$, the function $|x|^{-\alpha}$, with $1 \leq \alpha < n$ has that limit equal to $\infty$ at $0$.

However, you can still get some kind of affirmative result.

In general the limit in question is zero $\mathcal H^{n-1}$-a.e, where $\mathcal H^{n-1}$ denotes the $n-1$ dimensional Hausdorff measure.

This is Theorem 2.10 in *Measure Theory and Fine Properties of Functions* by Evans and Gariepy (2015 version).